# Hazelcast : waiting threads at abstractinvocationfuture.get

Tags: hazelcast

In our application we are using hazelcast 3.7.2 version and  most application threads seem to be slowing down in terms of processing it's tasks as most application threads are in a parked state on abstractinvocationfuture.get

Can you please share some insights on this?

com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:156)

Comment: Did you try checking out the status of GC on servers and clients? You can turn on verbose:gc and check the pattern of GC pauses. You can also use jstat to monitor the GC performance in a running application - server and/or client.

Comment: Hi wildnez, I saw and validated the gc logs.. there were no longer gc pauses per say. This entry from the threaddump is not seen on another node which performs the same functionality in parallel. Any insights as to why application threads are in waiting state on this trace?

Comment: Are you running IExecutorService Callable future tasks from client? If no then what kind of operations are invoked from clients?